# Why does child component re-render even if I have used useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const Root = () => {
  /** useState */
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [times, setTimes] = useState(1);

  const handleCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count * 2);
  }, []);

  const handleTimes = useCallback(() => {
    setTimes(times + 2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Root. counts: {count}</div>
      <Counter onClick={handleCount} value={count} />
      <Counter onClick={handleTimes} value={times} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The child component will re-render when parent component re-renders, so I don't know why I should use `useCallback`. When will the function in `useCallback` change without my component re-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `React.memo` in your child component.

This code will help you,

```js
export const Counter = React.memo(props => {
    return ...
})
```

Here is the doc [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Comment: He can do that, but it's adding unnecessary process creating additional overhead for no true benefit, and not addressing the core problem of how he's managing state.

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't defined a dependency array for either of your `useCallback`s. The child components would rerender if the function were rebuilt, or if the `value` were to change. Use should also be using the lazy set method of state.

```js
const handleCount = useCallback(() => {
  setCount(prev => prev * 2);
}, [setCount]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, dependency is needed. and I have searched online, no matter how I use hooks, child component will re-render when parent re-render, so useCallback seen to work with other hooks(useEffect, useRef)